# fail2ban: multiline "failregex" not working

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I'm using `fail2ban` on my debian-8-based host. I have several separate jails for detecting attacks on my SMTP server, and I would like to combine them into one single jail. Each of these jails utilizes a filter with a single `failregex` line, and this is working for me to detect these attacks. However, when I try to combine these into a single jail and a single filter with multiple `failregex` lines, the attacks are no longer being detected.

Here is a summary the multiple-jail-mulitple-filter setup which is currently working:

```
## from the 'postfixauth.conf' filter for the 'postfixauth' jail ...
failregex = ^.*lost connection after AUTH from unknown\[<HOST>\].*$

## from the 'postfixconcur.conf' filter for the 'postfixconcur' jail ...
failregex = ^.*concurrency limit exceeded:.*from unknown\[<HOST>\].*$

## from the 'postfixconnect.conf' filter for the 'postfixconnect' jail ...
failregex = ^.*(timeout|lost connection) after (RSET|AUTH|CONNECT|EHLO|STARTTLS) from unknown\[<HOST>\].*$

## from the 'postfixresolve.conf' filter for the 'postfixresolve' jail ...
failregex = ^.*hostname \S+ does not resolve to address +<HOST>.*$

## from the 'postfixsasl.conf' filter for the 'postfixsasl' jail ...
failregex = ^.*unknown\[<HOST>\]: SASL (PLAIN|LOGIN) authentication failed.*$

## from the 'postfixssl.conf' filter for the 'postfixssl' jail ...
failregex = ^.*SSL_accept error from unknown\[<HOST>\].*$
```

However, if I replace those six separate jails with a single jail with the following `failregex` in its filter file, it doesn't seem to be blocking those attacks:

```
## from the 'postfix.conf' filter for the 'postfix' jail ...
failregex = ^.*lost connection after AUTH from unknown\[<HOST>\].*$
            ^.*concurrency limit exceeded:.*from unknown\[<HOST>\].*$
            ^.*(timeout|lost connection) after (RSET|AUTH|CONNECT|EHLO|STARTTLS) from unknown\[<HOST>\].*$
            ^.*hostname \S+ does not resolve to address +<HOST>.*$
            ^.*unknown\[<HOST>\]: SASL (PLAIN|LOGIN) authentication failed.*$
            ^.*SSL_accept error from unknown\[<HOST>\].*$
```

My understanding (which might be mistaken) is that multiple `failregex` lines are legal, and that they are OR'ed together; *i.e.*, if any given line in the log file matches one or more of these regexes, then the line is considered to match and to signal a "fail".

Assuming that my understanding is correct, can anyone see what is wrong with the way in which I'm doing this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the problem I was having was unrelated to the change of multiple filters into a single filter with multiple `failregex` lines. I had an unrelated problem on my machine which occurred around the same time which I originally overlooked, and I mistakenly thought that the `fail2ban` filter was faulty.

After fixing the unrelated problem and restarting everything, the multi-line regex that I show above is indeed working.

**UPDATE**: To give more detail, the problem had nothing to do with `fail2ban`. Around the same time that I made the change to a multiline regex, I accidentally ran `/etc/init.d/iptables off` instead of `/etc/init.d/iptables stop`. This caused `iptables` not to start up after reboot, and all my `fail2ban` rules had no effect. Once I realized this error and started up `iptables` properly, the multi-line regex worked fine.

Comment: You are completely wrong about my having any intention of saying "I won't tell you". You project negative motives where no such childish projection is called for. Check my "UPDATE", above. I didn't originally post more, because my problem ended up having nothing to do with `fail2ban`. Now, I hope my update has made that clear. Have a nice day.